# As a new resident alien, can I harvest capital gain losses from previous years when I was a non-resident alien?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, capital-gains-tax, non-resident, capital-loss

In the year 2020, I switched from being a non-resident alien (NRA) to a resident alien (RA) for tax purposes. I'd come to the US in 2015 as an international student (F-1 visa).

For NRAs, using the capital losses reported in Schedule NER of Form 1040NR to offset taxable income is not allowed. Similarly, there is no concept of capital loss carryover either. Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

As RA, however, I am now allowed to harvest capital losses reported in Schedule D of Form 1040. My question is:
Can I use my capital losses from previous years to offset a capital gain reported in Schedule D, or offset taxable income?

In Turbotax, it only asks for losses reported in Schedule D, so I have a hunch the answer is no, but it would be great if I can get some clarity on the subject.